# Using Bitbucket Pipelines to deploy to multiple AWS regions using AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy

I have an existing Bitbucket Pipelines setup with AWS CodeDeploy that works on single region. Now I'm trying to modify the existing setup to cater for multi region deployment. Here's my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```html
image: php:7.1.29

pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip zip
            - zip -r MobileAPIDEV.zip .
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'MobileAPIDEV'
                ZIP_FILE: 'MobileAPIDEV.zip'
                COMMAND: 'upload' 
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'MobileAPIDEV'
                DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: 'MobileAPIDEV'
                WAIT: 'false'
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
                COMMAND: 'deploy' 
                IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES: 'true'
                FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: 'OVERWRITE'
    master:
      - step:
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip zip
            - zip -r prodMobileAPI.zip .
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'prodMobileAPI'
                ZIP_FILE: 'prodMobileAPI.zip'
                COMMAND: 'upload' 
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'prodMobileAPI'
                DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: 'prodMobileAPI'
                WAIT: 'false'
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
                COMMAND: 'deploy' 
                IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES: 'true'
                FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: 'OVERWRITE'
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY # Optional if already defined in the context.
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-central-1 
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'prodMobileAPI'
                DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: 'prodMobileAPI'
                WAIT: 'false'
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
                COMMAND: 'deploy' 
                IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES: 'true'
                FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: 'OVERWRITE'
```

I added the third `pipe` under master branch and set `eu-central-1` as the new default region. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly because I couldn't find any example for multi region deployment using this approach.

When I tried to deploy, I got this error: `An error occurred (RevisionDoesNotExistException) when calling the GetApplicationRevision operation: No application revision found for revision.`

I confirm that my CodeDeploy setup in the other region has the correct role, and the Access Key that I used for the Bitbucket Pipeline has sufficient permission as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From error

> An error occurred (RevisionDoesNotExistException) when calling the GetApplicationRevision operation: No application revision found for revision.

There is no artifact available in the mentioned region `eu-central-1`  [RevisionDoesNotExistException](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDeployment.html#API_CreateDeployment_Errors).

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-cross-region.html)

> When you create or edit a pipeline, you must have an artifact bucket in the pipeline Region and then you must have one artifact bucket per Region where you plan to execute an action.

So you have to have an `upload` section as well  `OR`

what I would do is have a separate step per `region` `OR`

setup [Cross-Region Replication for Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/), this would let me copy the articats whichever region I want to and I can have only one `upload` in the `pipeline.yml`

check this blog post [Using AWS CodePipeline to Perform Multi-Region Deployments](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-aws-codepipeline-to-perform-multi-region-deployments/)

```yaml
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip zip
            - zip -r MobileAPIDEV.zip .
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'MobileAPIDEV'
                ZIP_FILE: 'MobileAPIDEV.zip'
                COMMAND: 'upload' 
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'MobileAPIDEV'
                DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: 'MobileAPIDEV'
                WAIT: 'false'
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
                COMMAND: 'deploy' 
                IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES: 'true'
                FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: 'OVERWRITE'
    master:
      - step:
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip zip
            - zip -r prodMobileAPI.zip .
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'prodMobileAPI'
                ZIP_FILE: 'prodMobileAPI.zip'
                COMMAND: 'upload' 
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'prodMobileAPI'
                DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: 'prodMobileAPI'
                WAIT: 'false'
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
                COMMAND: 'deploy' 
                IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES: 'true'
                FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: 'OVERWRITE'
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'eu-central-1'
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'prodMobileAPI'
                ZIP_FILE: 'prodMobileAPI.zip'
                COMMAND: 'upload' 
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.5.3
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY # Optional if already defined in the context.
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'eu-central-1' 
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'prodMobileAPI'
                DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: 'prodMobileAPI'
                WAIT: 'false'
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
                COMMAND: 'deploy' 
                IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES: 'true'
                FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: 'OVERWRITE'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware that it's a requirement to have a bucket in the region I'm deploying to.